# Including ZFS in concatenated DD statement fails with abend S112 and message IEC908I 112-04

Tags: mainframe, zos

I tried to include zFS directories (rocket sw git client) in ASMA90/Syslib-concation. If a memer is found, the compile job abends with IEC908I 112-04. There is no difference if there are one or more SYSLIB DD-cards. 
It is no problem to read the same file with e.g. IEBGENER.

```
//SYSLIB   DD PATH='/u/myuid/git/myrepo/asm',            
//            PATHDISP=KEEP,PATHOPTS=(ORDONLY),            
//            LRECL=80,RECFM=FB,BLKSIZE=32720,FILEDATA=TEXT**

IEC908I 112-04,myuid,COMPILE ,SYSLIB                     
IEA995I SYMPTOM DUMP OUTPUT  926                           
SYSTEM COMPLETION CODE=112**
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot and best regards

Comment: For anyone else researching this, IEC908I is [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4.ieah700/m014998.htm) and the SYSLIB is basically right out of the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSENW6_1.6.0/com.ibm.hlasm.v1r6.asma100/mvsspeclib.htm).

Comment: I re-created the problem you have on my system.  Do you happen to know the z/OS Version and service level ?

Comment: I updated the title to accurately reflect the problem and removed the tag referencing Git as it is not related to the actual issue.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to successfully re-create the abend locally.

First, what you are trying to do is correct and should work; except that there is most likely an APAR installed on your system that is causing the error.

The problem was introduced in PTF `UJ00405` by APAR `OA56487`
 and has been corrected with APAR `OA58404`.  What you are seeing is a bug.

If you are the systems programmer than you need to get the APAR / PTF listed as `OA58404` and get that APAR / PTF installed.  You need to contact IBM service to get that information.

I did test your scenario on an internal system that did not have the `UJ00405` installed and it works correctly.

So, your issue is a bug, not something you did wrong.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot and yes, it helps. I was sysprog some year but in my new Company I have talk with my colleagues. Best regards & merry Christmas

Comment: @zOSFanboy Ur welcome, I know the information is time dated but if this answers your question flag the answer as such so other people will see their was a solution to your question.  You saved me from  the drudgery of e-mail yesterday so thank you :)